# TFS makes checkins as another user instead of my current user

Tags: visual-studio-2010, checkin

i have a public workspace for my user 'domain\user'

when visual studio starts from my user, it automatically create another workspace for user 'domain\user1'

all checkins a perfomed by 'domain\user1'

both of users have full administrative permissions in TFS project collection

result of **TF WORKSPACES** :

```
Collection: http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/collection1
Workspace   Owner              Computer  Comment
--------- --------------------- --------- ----------
workspace1  domain\user1       computer1
workspace1  domain\user        computer1
```

It seems that my workspace,by some unknow reasons, not visible to visual studio.

When i set 'public(limited)' or 'private' for workspace with owner 'domain\user', VS give error during check-in:

[image: screen]

Does anyone help me to understand what is happening? Recently it works well, but it looks that something is going wrong..

UPDATE: it is appears only on one computer 'computer1' and works fine on different mashine with same user login

Comment: Can you restart that particular system and make sure you login under the correct credentials. Sometimes something like a password expiry policy makes the a user account on a system invalid when the password expires and the system remains active.

Comment: yes, tfs server been restarted, my computer also many times restarts, but nothing changes. It seems to webservice request to checkin going with wrong credentials(checkout works well for my user)

Comment: After some time it fixes in itself, maybe someone configure server..

Answer (score 2):

After some time it appears again on new environment.

I solve it by next steps:
1) go to control panel -> credential manager
2) under 'windows credentials' find row with your TFS server url
3) click remove

When your connect to tfs next time from VS, it requests credentials and you need enter actual login and password